# SQL Server Services won't start and database engine can't be accessed

Tags: sql-server, sql, windows-10, service

So my SQL server can't be connected to after the computer crashed while connecting to it over RDP. The MSSQLSERVER, UALSVC and MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS services are all set to automatic (the ualsvc is set to delayed start) but none of them start and even when I manually do it they immediately stop. I had an event notification called Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power and its severity is critical. When I try to connect to the database engine I get this error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Database Engine
Cannot connect to [name redacted].
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried manually restarting the services, shutting down, restarting basically all the main troubleshoot steps for someone who does not know much about this. It happened right after a crash so I assumed it was just a glitch and was the hoping a restart would fix it but it did not. I really need access to this database.

Comment: As a start, I'd look at both the error log for SQL Server itself (the location of which you can find in the startup parameters for the service in the SQL Server Configuration Manager) as well as Window Event Logs. The error that you have posted above is expected at this point; clients can't connect to a service that isn't running.

Comment: Check Windows Event Viewer and SQL Server Configuration Manager for configuration accuracy. Use SQLCMD or OSQL commands to inspect and repair system databases if needed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Ensure sufficient hard drive space, addressing any disk space issues before restarting SQL Server services. Lastly, restore last known good system DB backups with SQLCMD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It could that the system databases are damaged/corrupted due to the crash.

Here is howto to repair

1. Insert the SQL Server installation media into the disk drive, or,
   from a command prompt, change directories to the location of the
   setup.exe file on the local server. For SQL Server 2022 (16.x), the
   default location on the server is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2022.
2. From a command prompt window, enter the following command. Square brackets are used to indicate optional parameters. Don't enter the brackets. When using a Windows operating system that has User Account Control (UAC) enabled, running Setup requires elevated privileges. The command prompt must be run as Administrator.

   `setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts [ /SAPWD= StrongPassword ] [ /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName ]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So this didn't work and I'm wondering if a better option would be to make a new sql server and just install my backup of the database that I have saved. I'm not sure if this would be the right move and wanted to see what you thought.

Comment: @turdie - it could be a *lot* of things and suggesting a remedy without diagnosis can make the problem worse.

Answer (score 0):

Do backup all of databases. Reinstall MsSQL Server. Import databases, and try connect do server. Normally MSSQL Server shoud start automatic after power on your machine. Maby problem is in your OS.